# Can't import the colorama module

Tags: python-3.x, colorama

I installed `colorama`, but I keep running into problems.
It seems I can't import the `colorama` module.
Sorry I'm an absolute beginner.

Visual Studio Code picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please attach the error you are getting

Comment: Please also don't post pictures of code and errors - add them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed it correctly? Install colorama by typing `pip install colorama` in command prompt

Then try reloading / restarting your VS Code.

Check if the selected python interpreter in VSCode is the same as the one you installed coloroma. You can check by typing `where python` in command prompt and it will tell you the location.

`Get-Command python` if you are in Windows Powershell, or type `which python` in Mac

Comment: Well, reloading VS Code did actually solve the issue.